# How to make my page load centered using CSS, HTML or really basic javascript

Tags: javascript, web, alignment

Hello Ive made a page which has an image of width 1300px as its widest point.  I'm trying to make something which makes the page load with the centre of the page (where text etc. resides) in the middle of the browser.  Is there a simple way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in CSS, do this:

```
   body: {
       text-align: center
   }

   #main {
       text-align: left
       margin: 0 auto;
   }
```

The text-align center is for old IE6, whereas margin works for newer browsers.  #main is your main div that is to be centered.

Comment: margin-left and margin-right can be shortened to margin: 0 auto;

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the outer wrapper CSS:

```
width: <text width>px;
margin: 0px auto;
```

And make the image a centered background of the body:

```
background: url(image.png) top center;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to display some block elements (with fixed width) centered you need to use this rule:

```
margin:0 auto;
```

if inside an element you want to center some text, just set:

```
text-align:center;
```

if you want to center an absolute element (fixed widh aswell, i.e. 1300px) you need to be more tricky this way:

```
margin-left:-650px;
left:50%;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Body{margin: 0px;}
.wrapperDiv{Margin: 0 auto;}
```